# how to iterate and append Firebase data

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table view that prints out comments.

```
    Database.database().reference().child("main").child("posts").child(postID!).child("comments").queryOrdered(byChild: "id").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
        if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for testingkey in postsDictionary.keys {
                for post in postsDictionary {
                    //main comments
                    self.Comments.add(post.value)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.TableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

For every post available I want to look to see if it has a comment associated with it (nested comment) and if it does, append it to comments array.

```
Database.database().reference().child("main").child("posts").child(self.postID!).child("comments").child(testingkey).child("comments").queryOrdered(byChild: "post_id").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
    if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        for post in postsDictionary {
            // nested comments
            self.Comments.add(post.value)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.TableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
})
```

This is the attempted code to get the nested comments/ This is the pathway to get the nested comments. This is also what my JSON looks like.

```
post-1069: {
    "comment-487" : {
      "id" : "comment-487",
      "content" : "blah blah blah",
      "comments" : {
        "comment-489" : {
          "id" : "comment-489",
          "content" : "i love you",
          "post_id" : "post-1069",
          "reply_to" : "comment-487",
        },
        "comment-490" : {
          "id" : "comment-490",
          "content" : "help me",
           "post_id" : "post-1069",
          "reply_to" : "comment-487",

}}
```

Comment: It have replies too under single comment ? and what is your main expected output ?

Comment: @iOSGeek sorry I don't understand your first question. The expected output is to have main comments to a certain post and if any of those main comments have replies to them, the corresponding comments should be right under their main comments

Comment: The code and structure aren't really matching up for me. There's post-1069 but then comment-487 as a child and a comments node where you have more comments. Seems like you may want to denormalize this structure with the comments stored in a separate node with a child node that references the post. That would make the code more manageable as the deep paths will be reduced and easier to query if needed. Oh - and Firebase closures update the UI on the main thread so you can remove the DisptchQueue calls. Last thing is you will loose the order of the comments by iterating over them like that.